# tic tac toe without loop - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-events

I have this code, and I'm trying to figure out why my if statement for winner is not working. For now, I wanna check only if the first three boxes are "X", and if they are to declare a winner.

```js
let player1 = "X";
let player2 = "O";
let turn = "X";
let box1 = $('.box1').val();
let box2 = $('.box2').val();
let box3 = $('.box3').val();
let paragraph = $('p');

let everyBox = $('.everyBox');

everyBox.on('click', event => {
  if ($(event.currentTarget).attr('disabled')) {
    return;
  }

  if (turn == "X") {
    $(event.currentTarget).append(player1);
    turn = "O";
  } else {
    $(event.currentTarget).append(player2);
    turn = "X";
  }

  $(event.currentTarget).attr('disabled', true);

  myFunction();

});

function myFunction() {
  if (box1 == player1 && box2 == player1 && box3 == player1) {

    paragraph.text('player1 wins!').
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variables `box1`, `box2` and `box3` aren't dynamic reference to values. They are value when assigned.

You may correct your script behavior by moving thoses lines into `myFunction` function block:

```js
let player1 = "X";
let player2 = "O";
let turn = "X";

let paragraph = $('p');

let everyBox = $('.everyBox');

everyBox.on('click', event=>{
    if ($(event.currentTarget).attr('disabled')) {
        return;
    }

    if(turn=="X"){
        $(event.currentTarget).append(player1);
        turn="O";
    }
    else{
        $(event.currentTarget).append(player2);
        turn="X";
    }

    $(event.currentTarget).attr('disabled', true);

    myFunction();

});

function myFunction(){
    let box1 = $('.box1').val();
    let box2 = $('.box2').val();
    let box3 = $('.box3').val();

    if(box1 == player1 && box2 == player1 && box3 == player1){
        paragraph.text('player1 wins!').
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should not `append()` your text but use [`text(player1)`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) that allows you to define element text content.